# Wrong datetime is stored in database

Tags: mysql, datetime

My table looks something like this (..., date1, date2, date3, date4, date5, ...)

and code something like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$query = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO table (date1, date2, date3, date4, date5) VALUES ('$date','$date','$date','$date','$date');
```

Problem is that date2 have my server New York datetime, while date1, date3, date4 and date5 have London datetime.

How is that possible? I used the same variable $date for all attributes.
In table they are all defined as `datetime NOT NULL`.

Comment: check in database table whether it is DATE or DATETIME data type

Comment: it is a DATETIME data type, same as other attributes.

Comment: i posted answer you can check it. hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with mysqli (I actually use PDO) but maybe you should verify if your database has default values for you date fields.

Also, if I'm not wrong, you shoud use double quotes in your query.

Finally, **you should take care about SQL Injection** ([wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)). You're query may be vulnerable.

Regards,

Jonathan F.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add backtick change '$date' into '" .$date . "'

```
"INSERT INTO `table` (`date1`, `date2`, `date3`, `date4`, `date5`) VALUES ('" .$date . "','" .$date . "','" .$date . "','" .$date . "','" .$date . "');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out what caused the problem. date2 attribute was actually named last_activity_date, and that name caused the problem. I'm not sure why that name caused the problem, but when I renamed it, problem disappeared.